# Meteor with haml

Tags: haml, meteor

Does Meteor support haml?

If a package needs to be created, what would be the recommended library to use?

Is do haml and handlebars play nice together?

I would like to write haml, that would be processed into the html style (with handlebars) that is shown in the Meteor demos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a smart package for 9elements haml-coffee.

You can clone my fork of meteor here: https://github.com/huetsch/meteor/tree/devel .

I've also created a pull request that's located here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/138 .

Comment: Ah, that was you. I saw the package appear on NPM with my name and wondered who pushed it.

Comment: I just tried this out using HAML['filename'], getting an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: HAML is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Meteor does not currently have a smart package for haml. Haml and handlebars should work together just fine as, like coffeescript, haml is pre-processed and meteor would only ever see the generated html.

The docs on smart packages for meteor are here: http://docs.meteor.com/#smartpackages

But as it says, the api is rapidly changing and undocumented so your best bet is to look at an existing package and go from there. Here's coffeescript's: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/coffeescript